# ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 36276416 into shape (96,227,227,1)

Tags: python, deep-learning, cnn

I am running my LeNet code with LFW, but when I run it, I am getting the following error message:

Here is the code that it is getting the error

```
# Import the packages
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

# Image Data Augmentation
train_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
val_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)
test_generator = ImageDataGenerator(rotation_range=2, horizontal_flip=True, zoom_range=.1)

# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(xtrain)
val_generator.fit(x_val)
test_generator.fit(xtest)

# Construct the image generator for data augmentation
aug = ImageDataGenerator(width_shift_range=0.1, height_shift_range=0.1,
                         horizontal_flip=True, fill_mode="nearest")
```

I then added the following

```
# Fitting the augmentation defined above to the data
train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(96, 227, 227, 1))
val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(96, 227, 227, 1))
test_generator.fit(xtest.reshape(96, 227, 227, 1))
```

but then got this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 134, in <module>
    train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(96, 227, 227, 1))
ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 36276416 into shape (96,227,227,1)
```

I have added the full code for more help on how to combat this issue. What is the fix for something like this?

UPDATE:
I then made the following changes to:

```
train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
val_generator.fit(x_val.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
test_generator.fit(xtest.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
```

to indicate that the value shall be computed automatically, but then when I run it. I get this error message:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\PycharmProjects\LeNet\LeNet.py", line 135, in <module>
    train_generator.fit(xtrain.reshape(-1, 227, 227))
  File "C:\Users\JoshG\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\image_data_generator.py", line 935, in fit
    raise ValueError('Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. '
ValueError: Input to `.fit()` should have rank 4. Got array with shape: (704, 227, 227)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is normal that it can't be reshape, because:

36276416 / (96*227*227*1) = 36276416 / 4946784 = 7.33333333

which is not an integer result.

Maybe there is a problem with some images' size or color formats.

Have you checked if all images are correctly sized and formatted?

Comment: So I checked the images and they are all gray-scaled instead of color. Would that make a difference?

Comment: Could be: colors are usually a set of 3 features (red, green and blue), whereas gray scale has only one. You should check which is each dimension requested and which is each dimension in input.

Comment: So I updated the code, and got a different error message. The question was updated with new error